# XPages and Rich Text - " Item Note already exists" error

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus

I'm migrating a Lotus Notes application to XPages. One Lotus Notes Form has a rich text item so on the XPage I added a Rich Text control and bound it to the item on the Notes form. Now whenever I edit the XPages document and make a change in the rich text editor, on saving I get the error " Item Note already exists". Is there any way of solving this prolem? I'm using 8.5.3. The rich text field on the Notes form is called "Note". Ideally I would like to be able to edit the documents both in the Lotus Notes client and in XPages. Here is the code on my XPage:

```
<xp:inputRichText id="NoteRT" value="#{document1.Note}" style="height:150.0px;      width:300.0px" rendered="#{javascript:currentDocument.isEditable()}">
<xp:this.dojoAttributes>
<xp:dojoAttribute name="toolbarType" value="Slim">
</xp:dojoAttribute>
</xp:this.dojoAttributes>
</xp:inputRichText>
<xp:text escape="false" id="NoteRead" rendered="#{javascript:!currentDocument.isEditable()}" value="#{document1.Note}"></xp:text>
```

Comment: This suggestion won't fix your issue, but you don't need both the `inputRichText` and `text` components; if the data source isn't in edit mode, the rich text component will display read-only... with formatting preserved.

Comment: I'm now developing my application on a Notes 9 server and I no longer have this problem. I use a computed field as my CSS style is automatically applied to this element which is not the case with the rich text field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO67696

and here 
http://cynology1.rssing.com/browser.php?indx=2286169&item=1718

you can read, that this is an error which is already fixed in fix pack2

but if you have no time to update to fp2, you could try to change the property of computeWithForm of the data from 'both' to 'onLoad' or 'onSave'.

go this way
xpages->properties->data->data->dominoDocument[0]->computeWithForm

I don´t know, which is right for your case, just try it and tell us if its helped.